# Save incoming text message in file in external Storage in Android

Tags: android, sms, file-handling

I am Trying to Save every incoming SMS in text file in external memory with following code.
For small Message or i works but when message get long and have many spaces this code just save last few line in text file .i can't figure out the problem.
Any thought?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().toString();

                //file name will be current time for uniquess

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMMM_yyyy__HH_mm_ss__a");
                String fileName = sdf.format(c.getTime());

                File myFile = new File("/sdcard//SaveSMS/"+getName(senderNum,context)+"//"+ fileName +    ".txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                // Append Body SMS to Stream
                myOutWriter.append(message);
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();

                Toast.makeText(context,"This SMS will save in SaveSMS\\"+senderNum, 1).show();                      

            } 
          } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

**Example of Error:** If someone text

1
1
1
2
3

4

5
6
6
7
8
9

7
6
5

this code will only save

6
5

Answer (score 0):

is it overwriting the data in existing file ? try replacing

`new FileOutputStream(myFile);`

with

`new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);`

Comment: thanks for reply but it doesn't make any difference.. i think there is some problem with message string..may be escape sequence in message string are making problem..but i can't figure it out..